# Software RAID-1 on Windows 7 doesn't work as expected

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, sata

Because of problems with the RAID config on my motherboard, I've decided to go the "easy" way and use software RAID.

So I made one big mirrored partition on my two identical hard drivers. I copies a bunch of files and felt somewhat happy and reassured.

I decided to try and see if my RAID *really* works so I stopped the PC and detached one of the hard drives. When I restarted the PC, there were a few things that had happened:

1. Windows didn't warn me in any way that there was something wrong
2. The mirrored volume was missing. But it is surely possible to work with one HDD only, isn't it?
3. By firing up *Disk Management* I got the following explanation: because the disk was missing the RAID had failed.

Does anyone have experience with software raids. This kind of behaviour really freaked me out. It's both inconvinient and dangerous. Why, how would I be able to make some backup if one of the disk fails and I don't have access to the mirrored partition? Could anyone suggest something more reasonable?

To top it all, my new pair of *7200.12 Barracudas* sound really distressing. On start or stop they make some very disturbing scratchy noise (not like jammed heads though, no clicking or anything). I'm desparate with the way things are going.

Thanks.

Comment: To answer part 2 of your question and assuming you indeed created mirror and not a stripe: Yes, the volume should still have been accessible.  As to " Why, how would I be able to make some backup ". **RAID IS NOT A BACKUP**.  Imagine a fire, a short circuit, theft, ... RAID is not going to help you with that. The only good backup is an off-site backup. Preferably an off-site off-line backup.

Comment: This is not a question.  Within the body, there are some vague questions, but none of them strikes me as THE question.  I'm somewhat disappointed that @Hennes edited this as if it were a real question instead of the junk/cruft it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I think I may go for [FlexRAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexRAID).</s>

I'll just use rsync with a GUI like [QtdTools](http://qtdtools.doering-thomas.de/page.php?seite=0&sub=0&lang=en). Works like a charm.

Comment: Could you maybe delete this post and add it to your original? This doesn't count as an answer because, well....it isn't one, it's a step your taking to try and solve your problem. Once you edit your original post, your question will be 'bumped' and will still have 0 answers. It will attract people much quicker.